# Angular error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

there is a lot about this subject in the WEB but none of the solutions I've seen solved my problem.

For context I have a project that has the top level module app.module and a sub module called pages.module.

Inside the sub module I have a component that is using Reactive forms.

I have imported **ReactiveFormsModule** in both of the module files:

Basically I have my app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my submodule file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class PagesModule { }
```

Unfortunately I still keep getting the error:
**NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.**

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong I would reward with internet points.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should the PagesModule maybe also be imported in the AppModule..?

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot. I know. Rookie mistake. Please post as an answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 0):

As answered by MikeOne in the comments I was missing the import of the PagesModule in my AppModule.ts